# Adding new line in jQuery tooltip plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-tooltip

I am now using jQuery tooltip plugin to create some quick reminders for users during data input. Here is the jQuery tooltip I am using:
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/

However, I have encountered a problem.
How can I add a new line in the body of the tooltip?

I have tried the following codes, but still cannot get it done.

```
<a href="Local Number: 2255-1234 \n Foreign Number:" id="TelephoneGuide" title="Data Input Example:">?</a>
<a href="Local Number: 2255-1234 &#010; Foreign Number:" id="TelephoneGuide" title="Data Input Example:">?</a>
```

So could anyone help me on this issue?

Thanks~

Comment: Are you sure you want that text in the href attribute? Browsers won't usually accept that as a valid URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think

```
<br/>
```

should do the trick.

For example:

```
<a href="Local Number: 2255-1234 <br/> Foreign Number:" id="TelephoneGuide" title="Data Input Example:">?</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried your HTML. You can't put tags in HTML attributes.

Comment: I am quite surprised on this method because it works perfectly.
I haven't even thought about it before, like what Samich said before, normally we can't put tags in HTML attributes, but I think jQuery UI somehow handle that for me.
Anyway, you rock! Paulius.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a line break? I'd recommend using a CSS rule to add a margin to the anchor tag. Else insert some `<br />`'s between the 2 `a` tags.

Comment: CSS is one of my greatest enemies when doing web-based development. However I think I should give it a try on your method. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could "encode" your line breaks and use the bodyHandler attribute, like:

The documentation shows examples of linking to a #id in the href, which will display the content of that #id. So place a element with your and #id somewhere on your page, and specifiy that as the tooltip, like:

```
<a id="yourLink" href="Hello#world">Some text</a>

$("#yourLink").tooltip({ 
    bodyHandler: function() { 
        var href_value = $(this).attr("href");
        return href_value.replace("#","<br/>");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using it this way (jQuery 1.9 and standard tooltip function):

```
$(".myClass").tooltip({
    content: function() {
        return $(this).attr('title');
    }
})
```

And then in the title you can use HTML

Example:

```
<span title="Line1 <br> Line 2 <br> <b>Bold</b><br>">(?)</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just paste the HTML as string, as other people said you have to use content.